# What is the practical implication of positive void coefficients in certin types of nuclear reactors?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

One difference between the Chernobyl disaster, on the one hand, and the Three Miles Island and the Fukushima disaster, on the other, is that Chernobyl's RBMK reactor design implied a positive void coefficient, i.e. a positive feedback loop in the case of a loss-of-coolant accident. Another way to put it, if I'm not mistaken, is that the Chernobyl reactor went prompt critical, while the other two didn't.

That said, does this have practical implications once the coolant has been lost? One way or the other, the end result is a core meltdown and (non-nuclear) explosions (at least at Chernobyl and Fukushima).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any engineering context, positive feedback loops are generally bad things and best avoided. In the case of the [Chernobyl disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster), the positive void coefficient resulted in catastrophic steam and hydrogen explosions within a few seconds of the emergency shutdown ("scram") command which triggered the incident.

A negative void coefficient gives you more time to take remedial actions in the case of a loss of coolant incident. In the case of the [Fukushima disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fukushima_nuclear_disaster) the total loss of power throughout the region, partial flooding of the site, and disruption of local transport links meant that there was very little that initial responders could do. Even so, the first hydrogen explosion did not occur until the day after the earthquake and tsunami. In the case of the [Three Mile Island accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Mile_Island_accident) a combination of faulty equipment and operator errors led to the release of contanimated coolant steam into the environment and a partial meltdown of the reactor core. However, the containment building itself was not breached, unlike Chernobyl and Fukushima.

Comment: So, the difference boils down to the speed at which one gets to a meltdown (and explosion): in the case of a prompt criticality accident, there's virtually no time to react (which makes sense given that it's called "prompt"). What about the strength of the explosion, do you know if that was influenced by the prompt-criticality nature in Chernobyl?

Answer (score 2):

RBMK design has its intrinsic positive feedback not only when the coolant is lost in one way or another, but also in its normal operation. This makes it especially sensitive to any loss of control governance (e.g. a control room blackout). A blackout that includes the reactor cooling pumps almost invariably goes bad because the pumps themselves have their own bad behavior at elevated coolant temperatures (their efficiency goes down as the water goes hotter).

All these things (and a lot of other things) combined led to a very quick development of a failed experiment (which itself was pretty much safety-related and motivated by the known at the moment RBMK safety deficits) into the worst-ever disaster. The interval between the last bad decision and the point of no return was less than a minute.

---

In contrast, we usually don't ever see in the news something about another Soviet reactor design (VVER) that has much larger installed base world-wide (tens of them up and running as of now, as well as back when Chernobyl made the news). It's not because failures don't happen, it's because the failures thereof develop at slow enough pace to be manageable by normal humans in a normal command chain.

---

Fukushima disaster was in no sense a reactor design fault. It was a power station design fault, a management fault and checks and balances fault.

Comment: To be fair, there are also eight RBMK reactors [still up and running](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RBMK#List_of_RBMK_reactors) as of this date (including two first-generation units [right next door to the second-biggest city in Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leningrad_Nuclear_Power_Plant)). If it weren't for that single colossal screwup at Chernobyl, they'd actually have a pretty decent statistical safety record by now.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Once they fixed the braindead control rod design and started accounting for the reactor's local reactivities, the reactor became more or less manageable. The control systems improved a lot since 1986 as well.